# How to access file on a remote server and get the file data as return value in perl?

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to write a perl script which will read a file on a remote server, alter some parameters inside the file and get whole file data or specific data as a return value.

Actually what I was thinking is to use cpan `openssh` utility to create a ssh connection, then call the script on the server side, which does all the reading and changing the parameters value. But the problem in this approach is that I will get only *success* or *failure* as a return value - not the file data.

Can anyone please tell me how I will achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [Show your research.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could use a simple http server and have some `/cgi-bin/modfile.pl` there. Then, you could use the combined knowledge of 15 years Perl+WEB to solve this ;-) Compared to your preferred `ssh:22` solution, a standard `http:80` variant would be extremely simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do what you are asking with `Net::SSH::Expect`

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
      host => "some.example.net", 
      password=> 'your-password', 
      user => 'you', 
      raw_pty => 1
    );

my $login_output = $ssh->login();
if ($login_output !~ /Welcome/) {
    die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
}
$ssh->exec("perl -i -pe 'tr/9/a/;' temp.txt");
my $cat=$ssh->exec("cat temp.txt");
print($cat);
```

The file on the remote server (temp.txt) contains just one line `0123456789`
and running the script has this output

```
$ perl /tmp/a.pl
012345678a
```

The main point here is that with this module I can log in to a remote machine and execute commands as I would with any other `ssh` session.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam for ur answer. It worked for me in one shot only, but I am thinking can we use cpan RPC:PIclient to achieve this functionality in much simpler way, becoz as far as I know, cpan Net:SSH utility is very slow and is not recommended to use in our scripts.